# CardImgOverlay in Reactstrap

Tags: reactjs

I'm working with the Card component of Reactstrap in React.

So what I need is a given image as the background for the card heading and card title. So I refered the documentation and used `CardImgOverlay` component

Given below is the code snippet

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Form, Card, CardTitle, CardText, CardImg, CardImgOverlay, Container, Row, Col } from 'reactstrap'
import './style.css'

class WeatherComponent extends Component{
    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                <Container>
                    <Row>
                        <Col>
                            <Card>
                                <CardImg width="50%" src="assets/images/sunny.jpg" alt="Card image cap" />
                                <CardImgOverlay>
                                    <CardTitle className='text'>Weather</CardTitle>
                                    <CardText className='text'>Summer</CardText>
                                </CardImgOverlay>
                            </Card>
                        </Col>
                    </Row>
                </Container>
            </div>
        )}
}    
export default WeatherComponent
```

But the above page is not rendering correctly and what I'm getting is this:

[image]

A solution to fix this problem is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';

Comment: Just out of interest, why did it render properly after importing this?